# How to implemented to a shared interface pulled from a WAR

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a web service we'll call service.war.  It implements an interface we'll call ServicePluginInterface.  During the startup of service.war, it reads in environment variables and uses them to search for a jar (MyPlugin.jar).  When it finds that jar, it then uses a second environment variable to load the plugin within the jar.  The class that it loads looks like this:

```
public class MyPlugin implements ServicePluginInterface {...}
```

The servlet attempts to load the plugin using code like:

```
try {
        if (pluginClass == null) {
            plugin = null;
        }
        else {
            ZipClassLoader zipLoader = new ZipClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader(), pluginJar);
            plugin = (ServicePluginInterface)zipLoader.loadClass(pluginClass).newInstance();
            plugin.getAccount(null,null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
```

The trick is that I don't have source or a jar for ServicePluginInterface. Not wanting to give up so easily, I pulled the class files out of the service.war files. By using those class files as dependencies, I was able to build, without compiler warnings, MyPlugin.  However, when actually executed by Tomcat, the section of code above generates a runtime exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.whatever.MyPlugin cannot be cast to com.whomever.ServicePluginInterface
```

---

As a second point of reference, I am also able to construct a synthetic class loader (separate java executable that uses the same class loading mechanism.  Again, since I do not have the original source to ServicePluginInterface, I used the class files from the WAR.  This second, synthetic loader, or faux-servlet if you will, CAN load MyPlugin just fine.  So I would postulate that the Tomcat JVM seems to be detecting some sort of difference between the classes found inside the WAR, and extracted class files. However, since all I did to extract the class files was to open the WAR as a zip and copy them out, it is hard to imagine what that might be.

---

Javier made a helpful suggestion about removing the definition of ServicePluginInterface, the problem with that solution was that the ZipClassLoader that the servlet uses to load the plugin out of the jar overrides the ClassLoader findClass function to pull the class out of the JAR like so:

```
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
ZipEntry entry = this.myFile.getEntry(name.replace('.', '/') + ".class");

if (entry == null) {
  throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
}
...
}
```

The class ZipClassLoader then recursively loads all parent objects and interfaces **from the jar**. This means that if the plugin jar does not contain the definition for ServicePluginInterface, it will fail.

Comment: Why doesn't ZipClassLoader delegate into its parent? Which implementation is it?

Comment: Well unfortunately I think that ZipClassLoader is copyrighted to the servlet owner, so I can't share it in its entirety, but now I'm wondering if it might be possible to write a better ZipClassLoader and replace the class file in the WAR...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes defined by different class loaders are **different**:

> At run time, several reference types with the same binary name may be
>   loaded simultaneously by different class loaders. These types may or
>   may not represent the same type declaration. Even if two such types do
>   represent the same type declaration, they are considered distinct. [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.4)

In that case `zipLoader` returns an instance of `MyPlugin` that implements the *other* `ServicePluginInterface` (is it loaded from the zip too?):

```
(ServicePluginInterface)zipLoader.loadClass(pluginClass).newInstance();
```

It seems that the application server already has a definition of `ServicePluginInterface`, then you don't need to redeploy it. It should be enough to add the required files (`ServicePluginInterface`, etc.) as non-deployed dependecies of your project.

Another approach goes by living with the fact, and accessing methods in `ServicePluginInterface` via reflection (use the `Class` object returned by `zipLoader`, instead of `ServicePluginInterface.class`).

Comment: Very helpful comment about the class loaders - I suspect the real trick lies somewhere in that area.

Unfortunately, and for reasons heretofore unknown to you, I believe this will not solve my issue due to the nature of the ZipClassLoader.  I've added the details to the end of the question where they can be nicely formatted, but the short of it is that ZipClassLoader fails unless the interface is also found in the JAR.

As for the second suggestion, unfortunately it is not possible to modify the servlet loader code as it was provided by a third party and I do not have the source code.

Comment: So I'll mark your answer as accepted as it's probably the more generally applicable and helpful solution.  What I actually ended up doing was completely overwriting both the ZipClassLoader class files with one of my own that directly loads (without opening a JAR) the Plugin class - which of course then I also had to place inside of the WAR.  Ugly hack, but it worked...